Counting comparisons in C++ insertion sort
I am doing a simple insertion sort on an array with a swap helper function; I am trying to do a count of comparisons and swaps, and I was able to figure out the swap count, but I cannot figure out the comparisons.
In the function, I wrote that for each swap, there is inherently a comparison (I think), and this is in the while loop, but I'm trying to figure out how to show that comparisons are still taking place even when a swap hasn't taken place.
int swaps = 0;
int comparisons = 0;

void InsertionSort(int numbers[], int size) {
   int i;
   int j;
   for (i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
      j = i;
      while (j > 0 && numbers[j] < numbers[j - 1]) {
            comparisons++;
            Swap(numbers, j, j  - 1);
            swaps += 1;
            j--; 
      }
      PrintNums(numbers, size); 
      }   
   }


Presuming it is the comparisons of the subject data you want to count, not “administrative” comparisons like simple loop bounds, remove comparisons++; and change numbers[j] < numbers[j - 1] to (comparisons++, numbers[j] < numbers[j - 1]).

Unrelated:, that bears a striking resemblance to bubble sort; not insertion sort.

Side note : Why are you still programming in "C" style void InsertionSort(int numbers[], int size)  (Whoever taugth you this was not teaching you "C++"). in current C++ this should be void InsertionSort(std::span<int> numbers). And Swap should be std::swap. From a design point of view, printing should never be part of a sort method.

@WhozCraig No, it's selection sort that bears resemblance to bubble sort. Notice that this one is linear when the data are already sorted.

Pass a comparison argument that defaults to the standard library's std::less. So the sort function can be called without counting comparisons or with a different sort metric (e.g. std::greater).
template <typename Less = std::less<int>>
void InsertSort(int* const numbers, std::size_t const size, Less const less = Less{}) {
  for (std::size_t i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
    for (std::size_t j = i; j > 0; --j) {
      if (less(numbers[j], numbers[j-1])) {
        std::swap(numbers[j], numbers[j-1]);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }   
}

int main() {
  int numbers[] = {3,45,1,5,2,0};
  std::size_t comparisons = 0;
  InsertSort(numbers, std::size(numbers), [&comparisons](int a, int b) {
    ++comparisons;
    return a < b;
  });
  PrintNums(numbers, std::size(numbers));
}

Note that swapping is not counted, but you can easily adapt this idiom to also count swaps.
